# How do I define a shape using tf.random_crop of variable patch sizes?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to get random crops from an image of different size (size changes over time and is stored in a `Variable`). The size of patches changes and represented as a tensor:

```
patch_size = tf.Variable(128)
patches = []
for i in xrange(num_patches):
  patch = tf.random_crop(images, [batch_size, patch_size, patch_size, 3])
  patches.append(patch)
patches = tf.stack(patches, axis=0)
patches.set_shape([num_patches, patch_size, patch_size, 3])
```

But I've got an error `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Tensor'` in the last line. The reason I have the last line is that my code down the line requires number of channels to be specified, otherwise I get `ValueError: The channel dimension of the inputs should be defined. Found 'None'.`

Eventually, I managed to make it work with this:

```
patches.set_shape([num_patches, None, None, 3])
```

But then I have the following lines:

```
net = slim.flatten(net)
logits = slim.fully_connected(net, 1, activation_fn=None)
```

Which now fail with `ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to`Dense`should be defined. Found 'None'.`

So this is still an issue. What can I do to handle image crops of variable sizes?

Comment: Does `patch_size` have to be a variable?

Comment: Yes, it changes over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `set_shape` method does not allow the shape to be defined with tensors. This is reasonable, because it does not make a TensorFlow operation. It actually redefines the static shape of the tensor on the spot.

Since `patch_size` is dynamic, it should not be used to set a static shape. Instead, as you already figured out, those dimensions must be left undefined:

```
patches.set_shape([num_patches, None, None, 3])
```

The second problem emerges because some operations require certain dimensions of the input to be defined. In particular, a fully connected layer keeps a matrix of weights `[#I, #O]`, where `#I` and `#O` are the sizes of the input and the output, respectively. Without a static shape at the input, this matrix cannot be initialized properly. A dense layer will not work right off the bat, even after a flatten (this just makes it so that `#I = W * H`). 2D convolutions work on the other hand, since the weight matrix only depends on the kernel size and the number of filters `[nf, kh, kw]`.

Inevitably, this dynamism comes with a certain price: your network model needs to work in a way that is independent with the incoming input sizes on the Height and Width dimensions. In CNN's, one possible approach is to perform a 1x1 convolution with `N` filters followed by a global average 2D pool. The shortest implementation of the latter is `tf.reduce_mean(x, [1, 2])`. At this point you have a tensor of static shape `[B, N]`, where `N` is statically known and `B` is just the batch size, which in typical cases can be `None`.